# AR/VR Vuforia Failed to Initialize

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, virtual-reality

I have gone through every possible adjustment variable I could find to try to try to make this work:

I adjusted sdk versions: **android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="22"**

I made sure that all my settings matched this: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Integrating-Cardboard-to-the-ARVR-Sample

I also followed these instructions for Android:
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/unity-player-settings

I even changed **AndroidManifest.xml** to be **AndroidManifest-Vuforia.xml**

I'm running
**Unity 5.3.0** / **Vuforia6.0.117** / **Samsung Galaxy S6 Active** / **And the latest google cardboard**

The program compiles and runs perfectly on my webcam, but the second I install it on my phone and run it, I keep getting the same **Vuforia Initialization Error** no matter what I do. And yes, I made sure to give the app permission to use the camera.

Can anyone help? I've scowered the internet and I cant get the thing to work.

Answer (score 1):

Under the 'Vuforia' menu, click 'Configuration', then disable the 'webcam' setting.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was because I didn't write my [Vuforia license key](https://developer.vuforia.com/targetmanager/licenseManager/licenseListingDetails). In the class `SampleApplicationSession` find the line thats similar to this:

```
Vuforia.setInitParameters(session.mActivityRef.get(), session.mVuforiaFlags, "KEY_HERE");
```

It could be on line `370` or `414`. But insert your key there and that could fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem in android studio to fix it I first get licenseKey from [here](https://developer.vuforia.com/vui/develop/licenses) and then go to Project->  app/cpp/Croossplatform/AppController of my projects  and then go to the

```
    namespace
{
    constexpr char licenseKey[] = "your key ";
}
```

line 55-60 AppController

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem in the Vuforia Unity package. Download the latest Vuforia-Unity package from https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk and import the new package into the project and replace the old package. This should resolve the error.

Other possible fixes that didn't seem to help in my case included: giving camera permissions in AndroidMainfest File, changing the Vuforia API key and disabling Vuforia Play Mode.